# Time and space complexity of if(!areAllArrayElementsZero())

Tags: algorithm

How can I calculate the time and space complexity of a program(pseudo code) as follows:

```
function(){
  if(!areAllArrayElementsZero()){
    if(hasAnyOdd()){
      decreaseOneFromFirstOddElementInArray()
    } else {
      divideAllArrayElementByTwo()
    }
  }
}
```

Here `areAllArrayElementsZero()`,`hasAnyOdd()`,`divideAllArrayElementByTwo()` has the complexity O(n). Any leads would help. Actually I was designing the solution to this [problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-minimum-steps-get-given-desired-array/).

Here is the Java equivalent of the above pseudo code, I've designed:

```
package competitive;

/*
* Problem: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-minimum-steps-get-given-desired-array/
*/
class formarray{
    private static int[] elem;

    private static boolean areAllZeros(){
        for(int i=0; i<elem.length;i++){
            if(elem[i]>0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean hasAnyOdd(){
        for(int i=0; i<elem.length;i++){
            if(elem[i]%2 != 0){
                // odd element discovered
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean decreaseFirstOddByOne(){
        for(int i=0; i<elem.length;i++){
            if(elem[i]%2 != 0) {
                // odd element discovered
                elem[i]-=1;
                // return true if one is decreased from first odd element
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static void DivideArrayElementsByTwo(){
        for(int i=0; i<elem.length;i++){
            // we are not checking element to be even as it has already been checked
            elem[i] = elem[i]/2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        elem = new int[args.length];

        // assign values
        for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
            elem[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }

        int steps=0;
        while(!areAllZeros()){
            if(hasAnyOdd()){
                // the array has odd members
                if(decreaseFirstOddByOne()){
                    steps++;
                }
            } else {
                DivideArrayElementsByTwo();
                steps++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Total steps required: "+steps);

    }
}
```

Comment: The function identified in the title does not appear in the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are exactly 4 paths of execution; sum up the cost of each, take the largest.

Or realize there are no loops and each path has a finite number of O(n) elements, making the whole thing O(n).